# Scala replace " by \"

Tags: scala, replace, double-quotes

How to replace the double quote by \":

```
val s = """I am "groot"."""
```

so the output will be """I am \"groot\"."""

I tried with but no luck

```
s.replaceAll('"', '\"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So @Tanjin provides the correct solution. However, the reason your solution does not work is this.

```
s.replaceAll('"', '\"')
```

Backslashes have special meaning in string and character literals, so `'\"'` compiles down to just the quote character. Running in the REPL will show you this

```
scala> '\"'
res2: Char = "
```

Meanwhile, using triple-quote strings disables this behavior.

```
scala> """\""""
res3: String = \"
```

Comment: best explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
s.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

How does this work:

```
s.replace(""""""", """\"""")
```

Comment: Almost tripped me up too because Java named its string methods poorly, but yes `replace` is preferable here.